# using callback in java with ExecutorService with Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a class that renders a GUI once a button a is selected. Within that GUI there is another button that has a listener attached and executes a thread with JAVA's ExecutorService

```
   public class ListenMenuAbout implements ActionListener {


       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           //Renders Gui

           JButton exampleButton = new JButton

           button.AddListener(new ListenBtnPupDownloadAll());


       }


   }



   public class ListenBtnPupDownloadAll implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


           executor.execute(new DownloadAll());


       }
   }
```

I would like to disable exampleButton for the duration the thread is running with exampleButton.setEnabled(false) and then when it has finished executing .setEnabled(true).

```
  while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

      btnPupDownloadAll.setEnabled(false);
  }
```

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: As with any similar problem, use an observer/observable so that the Swing thread is not waiting on this thread, but rather is *notified* by another thread when the process is complete. This is one great advantage of a SwingWorker in that it gives you back a Future and allows use of PropertyChangeListener to notify the Swing thread when execution is done. Why not use a SwingWorker here?